# Accessing a content provider of App1 from App2 when both are signed with the same key

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, signing

I have App1 with this build.gradle (the one in app folder) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.security.app1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("androidKey.jks")
            storePassword "StorePass123"
            keyAlias "MyAndroidKey"
            keyPassword "KeyPass123"
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("androidKey.jks")
            storePassword "StorePass123"
            keyAlias "MyAndroidKey"
            keyPassword "KeyPass123"
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

androidKey.jks is in the app folder as well. Manifest file of the application is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.security.app1">
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.providerPermission"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.providerPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name=".ContentProviderSecured"
            android:readPermission="${applicationId}.providerPermission">
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In app1 I can access ContentProvider

```
readCursor("com.example.security.app1.provider");
    private void readCursor(String pAuthority) {
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://" + pAuthority + "/query"), null, null, null, null);
            String res = "Result" + c.getCount() + c.getColumnNames()[0].toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Result", "Cannot access provider");
        }finally {
            if (c!=null){
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

but the same code in app2 gives me a Permission denial. App2 have the same keystore in its app folder and its build.gradle is identical to the app1 build.gradle file. These are the settings I used to create a key (one of the setting windows, the rest were creating passwords - the ones I use in build.gradle file) http://pokit.org/get/?e983d5190e38ad24c59158b87b6cedb0.jpg. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong - I believe it is related to signing, because if I remove that permission from the content provider I can get access to it. Thanks.

Comment: you are looking for which key? i think there is not required signingConfigs in your demo apps

Comment: First I wasn't using these signingConfigs in my app. I created keystore and signed the app and the result was .apk file (I signed both apps with the same key). But still the same issue. I then thought that maybe it is not installing that created apk when I run it on the phone, so I copied those apks to the phone and installed them manually but still the same issue.

Comment: why you are not replacing ${applicationId} with your app package?

Comment: You think that would help? I believe there is some issue with this permission and/or signing. Because when I remove it app2 can access app1's content provider (even with that ${applicationId}).

Comment: yea because without package how can set content provider permission  check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html also check your catch block log

Comment: This ${applicationId} evaluates to com.example.security.app1, is that what is should be, or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164251/discussion-between-ajay-pandya-and-mediha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the same code in app2 gives me a Permission denial.

app2 does not hold the `${applicationId}.providerPermission` permission, apparently. You need the `<uses-permission>` attribute for that custom permission in app2's manifest. In addition, either app2 needs to be installed after app1, or app2 will need the `<permission>` element as well.

Also, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, bear in mind that [there are security flaws inherent with custom permissions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: So, even apps are signed with the same I need to add     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.security.app1.providerPermission" /> this line to App2 manifest in order to use ContentProvider from app1? It is acually working, let me try sign app3 with different key and add that line to manifest.

Comment: It works, I added the permission to app3 but signed it with different key. Thank you both!

Comment: @Mediha: "even apps are signed with the same I need to add" -- yes. Using the same signing key is necessary because this is a `signature` permission. However, before that even comes into play, app2 needs to request the permission.

Comment: Thank you so much, I read that user doesn't need permission with that protectionLevel, but that meant he doesn't need to explicitly approve (like e.g. for writing to external storage).

Comment: @Mediha: That is correct... but you still have to ask for the permission in the manifest with `<uses-permission>`.